# AttributeError: module 'bpy_extras' has no attribute 'mesh_utils'

Tags: python

I am new to Blender & Python Scripting.
My Current setup us Blender 3.0 with Python 3.9.7

I tried to run the below script,for to get UV data and getting " AttributeError: module 'bpy_extras' has no attribute 'mesh_utils'"
The issue is same for script editor and Python Console.

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras

print(bpy_extras.mesh_utils.mesh_linked_uv_islands(bpy.context.active_object.data))
```

The auto complete doesnt list all the modules of bpy_extras. Refer the below picture

[image]

The work around to fix this issue is have to import the math_utils directly as below

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras import mesh_utils

print(mesh_utils.mesh_linked_uv_islands(bpy.context.active_object.data))
```

Though, i have a work around,
Could any one please help me what could be the issue and how to fix?

Comment: There is no problem, this is the way Python works when there is a large sub-package it needs to be explicitly imported like this. BTW, did you mean to write "mesh_utils" everywhere you wrote "math_utils"?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Understood now. Sorry its typo mistake. Its should be mesh_utils